# Symfony2 Append javascript flles from a form type template

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, twig

I am creating an image cropper as new form type in Symfony2 using the jQuery plugin imgAreaSelect ([website](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/)). In my form type template (imagecropper_widget.html.twig) I load jQuery and the plugins library.

As jQuery is loaded as well in my base.html.twig, the functions in the plugin library don't work anymore. Firebug throws an "is not a function" error.
If I remove in my base.html.twig the jQuery then it works well but of course that is not a solution.

It would be great if there would be a way to append the javascript files I need in that moment to the javascripts block. I tried to override the javascripts block from my theme but Symfony throws an error because I don't use or extend from another template.

So is there a legit way to append javascript files to a block that exists in the base.html.twig page?

Javascript block in base.html.twig:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts '@jquery_js' '@bootstrap_js' filter='?yui_js' combine=true %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

imagecropper_widget.html.twig

```
{% block imagecropper_widget %}
   {% spaceless %}
    <h2>Select the area</h2>
    <img src="http://localhost/project/web/test.jpg" id="imgc" style="width:100%" />

    {% block javascripts %}
        {% javascripts
        '@jquery_js'
        'bundles/imanagecmsfield/js/jquery.imgareaselect.js'
        'bundles/imanagecmsfield/js/process.js'
        filter="?yui_js"
        %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}

    {% endblock %}

  {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I usually do not put in the base template the scripts and css files *within* the javascript block. The Javascript block is usually empty and at the bottom of the base template.

base.html.twig:

```
{% javascripts 'XXX' %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}

{% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
```

This way, nothing will be overridden if I add site-specific scripts

otherside.html.twig:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ;
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you use `{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}` or `{% use '::base.html.twig' %}` in that case? If I use `use` Symfony throws the error Template "::base.html.twig" cannot be used as a trait in ..

Comment: I make use of {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}. I am not sure if "use" would make sense when inherit from the base template. But I never had this scenario.

Comment: The extending works great for views. In this case the template is for a form type. It even doesn't let me use that block from the template file, probaly because it just looks for the widget block. I am afraid I have to fall back on injecting the javascript via the view template which is far from the best solution.

Comment: Ok so the real problem is then, if you include two times the same script, here jquery.js. This behavior is not defined afaik for all the browser and it does obviously break jquery here. So the correct solution would be to check if this js has already been included. I do not remember a builtin function in twig for that, you may have to write an own extension?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind having multiple script tags ( and thus losing combining all assets ), you could simply overwrite the javascripts block and render the parent like so:

```
{% block javascripts %}
{{ parent() }}
{% javascripts  
    '@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/public/js/*.js'  
%}  
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>  
{% endjavascripts %}  
{% endblock %}
```

Otherwise you'll need to do some more work as described here https://symfonybricks.com/en/brick/smart-use-of-assetic-to-compress-javascripts-and-stylesheets , to make it truly configurable.

Which in combination with an event listener that actually adds your javascripts to the configuration array, should provide a more configurable solution I'd guess :-).

Comment: The parent function doesnt see to work with form types. Do you have an example that works?